# Regularly or Regular

Tags: compound-adjectives

Which one is correct:

> **10% off regular-priced items** or **10% off regularly-priced items**?

I see a number of American advertisements with the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

**Regular** is an [adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective). Definition is:

- Happening over and over again at the same time or in the same way: occurring every day, week, month, etc.
- Happening at times that are equally separated.
- Happening or done very often.

Ex: He is a regular contributor to the magazine.

**Regularly** is an [adverb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb). Definition is:

- At the same time every day, week, month, etc.: on a regular basis.
- Very often.
- With the same amount of space between each thing.

Ex: The sales team meets regularly.

Comment: Because of the difference in parts of speech, I would say that "regular price" and "regularly-priced" are more correct than "regular priced". It seems to me that "regular priced" is using the adjective as an adverb. 
(I'd also say that "regular price" is more common than "regular priced")

Comment: To me it seems like it should be either "regular-priced" (because compound or phrasal adjectives are usually hyphenated) or "regularly priced" (because phrasal adjectives where the first word ends with -ly are usually not hyphenated, at least as per Chicago Manual of Style).